# Python - parsing with multithreads and repeating proxy

Tags: python, multithreading, parsing, proxy, python-requests

**Description:** i try to parse a lot of data, but I get errors from the server when two thread with the same IP address are working. My number of proxies is not enough to solve the problem head on.

**Problem:** how can I make a call to threads repeating the proxy from the list, but checking the proxy for busyness and taking the free one to work?

**What i wanted:** my expectation is from the module "concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor" to give him a proxy list so that he repeats it and checks for busyness.

**What i tried:** now I filled out the proxy list for the entire range list = list * range // len(list). I also tried to select a proxy using random choice.

**My code (tabs are badly inserted):**

`def start_threads():
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=8) as executor:
        executor.map(get_items_th,range(500),proxy_list)`

```
def get_items_th(begin,proxy):
items=[]
headers={'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.3'}
r = requests.get('https://*.com/?query=&start='+str(begin*100)+'&count=100&search_descriptions=0&sort_column=popular&sort_dir=desc&norender=1', headers=headers,timeout=15000, cookies=cookie, proxies=proxy)
time.sleep(random.uniform(1.5, 2.5)) #it not helping, i'm looking for a better option

if r.status_code!=200:
    print('Error code '+str(begin)+': '+str(r.status_code))
else:

    page = json.loads(r.content)

    if page['results']!=None:
        allItems = page['results']

        for currItem in allItems: 
            hash_name=currItem['hash_name'].replace('}','')
            app_name=currItem['app_name']
            asset_description=currItem['asset_description']
            appid=str(asset_description['appid'])
            classid=str(asset_description['classid'])
            tradable=str(asset_description['tradable'])

            if '<body>' not in hash_name:
                items.append(classid+'}'+appid+'}'+app_name+'}'+hash_name+'}'+tradable+'\n')

        g = open ('items_'+str(begin)+'.csv', 'w',encoding='utf8')
        for line in items:
            g.write(line)
        g.close()
    else:
        print(r.content+'\n')
```

**Additional question:** Maximum number of threads = number of processor threads? I want to complete the task as fast as possible.

**Check image: [image_file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9gfjz.png)**

**updated file: [test3.7z - run.py](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zuoC_HP5d_oB6VPjmPkQSpRCoW447aHC/view?usp=sharing)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a Proxy class which can be work as a context, with the defined **enter** , and **exit** method, Then you can use it with the "with" statement.

```
import threading

PROXIES = {
    "PROXY1" : "1",
    "PROXY2" : "2",
    "PROXY3" : "3",
    "PROXY4" : "4",
    "PROXY5" : "5",
}

class Proxy():
    _Proxies = list()
    cls_lock = threading.Lock()

    def __init__(self,name,proxy):
        self.free = True
        self.name = name 
        self.proxy = proxy
        self.__class__._Proxies.append(self)

    @classmethod
    def Get_Free_Proxy(cls):
        with cls.cls_lock:
            while True:
                for proxy in cls._Proxies:
                    if proxy.free:
                        proxy.free = False
                        return proxy

    def __enter__(self):            
        return self

    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        self.free = True

for Key,Value in PROXIES.items():
    Proxy(Key,Value)

with Proxy.Get_Free_Proxy() as locked_proxy:
    print(locked_proxy)
    for Proxy in Proxy._Proxies:
        print(Proxy.name,Proxy.free)

print()

for Proxy in Proxy._Proxies:
        print(Proxy.name,Proxy.free)
```

This will print:

```
PROXY1 False
PROXY2 True
PROXY3 True
PROXY4 True
PROXY5 True

PROXY1 True
PROXY2 True
PROXY3 True
PROXY4 True
PROXY5 True
```

Then you can modify your code:

```
def start_threads():
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=8) as executor:
        executor.map(get_items_th,range(500))

def get_items_th(begin):
    with Proxy.Get_Free_Proxy() as locked_proxy:
        items=[]
        headers={'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.3'}
        r = requests.get('https://*.com/?query=&start='+str(begin*100)+'&count=100&search_descriptions=0&sort_column=popular&sort_dir=desc&norender=1', headers=headers,timeout=15000, cookies=cookie, proxies=locked_proxy)
        .
        .
        .
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213944/discussion-on-answer-by-ezisfoglalt-python-parsing-with-multithreads-and-repea).